# Razor Pages: Where to Get Correct Script Ref Syntax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Visual Studio 2017 by default creates references to scripts and CSS like this

```
<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha256-E/V4cWE4qvAeO5MOhjtGtqDzPndRO1LBk8lJ/PR7CA4=">
    </script>
</environment>
```

I guess it's slightly faster than fetching everything from my server. That's good for Bootstrap and jQuery. Then if I want to reference font-awesome, smoothscroll and other libraries, where can I find the right way to reference them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is about referencing other libs on `cdn` then your just need to google for `{libname} cdn`or you can browse [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/) and search for libraries you need. And you can reference script like this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/url"></script>
```

If you need `integrity` value for security reasons you can generate this hash by yourself using [this tool](https://www.srihash.org/#app) or read [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) for more information. If you need `asp-fallback-src` just download script from cdn, add it to project and reference it.